# Git в Android Studio: Как разбить часть изменений в файле построчно?

Tags: android-studio, git

[image: Неправильный диф студии]
Хочу закоммитить только часть строк из предлагаемых студией, как можно разделить изменения в этом блоке на два коммита?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, вместо ломтей `hunk` использовать редактирование патча напрямую:

```
git add -e имяфайла
```

Откроется редактор. Строки, начинающиеся с `+` были добавлены, `-` - удалены. Нужно оставить `+` и `-` там где нужно, а то что не нужно в коммите - стереть всю строку полностью.

Перед коммитом можно проверить, что получилось:

```
# будет добавлено в коммит
git diff --cached -- имяфайла
# НЕ будет добавлено в коммит
git diff -- имяфайла
```

Comment: В общем, до этого и дошел. А потом обновил эту страницу и увидел ваш ответ. Но все равно спасибо, я думаю еще пригодится таким же "зеленым" как я ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
git add --patch имяфайла
```

позволяет выбирать фрагменты файла для следующего коммита. После ввода этой команды изменения в файле разбиваются на блоки (*hunk*) и к каждому блоку появляется такой вопрос:

> Stage this hunk [y,n,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]?

<kbd>y</kbd> - включить в коммит, <kbd>n</kbd> - не включать в коммит (значения остальных опций можно [посмотреть тут](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) ближе к концу страницы).

В АС в меню VCS есть опция "Create Patch...", думаю, что она делает то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо! Удалось разделить hunk вручную: git add --patch имяфайла, ввел 'e' в терминале, в редакторе GNU nano оставил нужные строки, закоммитил их, затем закоммитил оставшиеся. Не очень удобно..  жаль, что студия не позволяет редактировать эти hunk'и интерактивно.